# How check progress of lvconvert --replace

Tags: lvm

I'm replacing few disks configured with RAID5 at LVM.

The command used to replace is

```
lvconvert --replace /dev/oldpv vgname/lvname /dev/newpv
```

It's start the process in background.
The parameter `-i #` have no effect , either `-v`

I try a lot of options at `lvs -o +<fields>` (and pvs, vgs) , no one return this progress..

I want check the progress because are big disks and fews LVs. 
This take few minutes running , I don't want to start the next LV while the current process still running...

For now I'm monitoring the I/O using dstats/iostats command but this is very ugly way to check this...

Comment: Isn't `Cpy%Sync` the right column for this in `lvs` output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about RAID5, but for mirrors use

```
# dmsetup status

rootvg-testmirror: 0 9216000 raid raid1 2 AA 3233673/9216000 idle 0
```

In this example its about 33% when you evalute 3233673/9216000

I haven't enough disks to create a test RAID5, but I'm sure it'll be something similar.

Comment: works perfectly . Do you know if exists some kind of better/friendly viewer for dmsetup status ? (I trying check the answer but the site is returning "an error has occurred" , I will try later).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on banjo67xxx's answer you can get the percent complete (with decimals) using the following:

```
echo "(`dmsetup status | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $8}'`)*100" | bc -l
```

If you want to limit the number of decimal places you use a scale declaration in the string echoed to bc. Here's the same command constrained to 2 decimal places:

```
echo "scale=2; (`dmsetup status | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $8}'`)*100" | bc -l
```

Comment: The required line might not be the last one in `dmsetup status` and the required column might not be the 8th one. I succeeded with `echo "100*$(dmsetup status | awk '/snapshot-merge/{print $5}')" | bc -l` for snapshot merging on Ubuntu 18.04.